# FileStream Class C# Input from txt file to array

Tags: c#, arrays, delimiter, streamreader

I am trying to make use of StreamReader and taking data from text files and store it into an array. I am having an issue where I think the fix is simple, but I am stumped. When I print the array, it prints every single token in the txt file instead of the single line of data containing the search name along with the 11 int tokens.
[Long_Name.txtsample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zS9S.png)

```
public class SSA
{
    public void Search()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name to search for?");
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        Search(n, "Files/Names_Long.txt");
    }
    public int[] Search(string targetName, string fileName)         
    {
        int[] nums = new int[11];
        char[] delimiters = { ' ', '\n', '\t', '\r' };
        using (TextReader sample2 = new StreamReader("Files/Exercise_Files/SSA_Names_Long.txt"))
        {
            string searchName = sample2.ReadLine();

            if (searchName.Contains(targetName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found {0}!", targetName);
                Console.WriteLine("Year\tRank");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} was not found!", targetName);

            while (searchName != null)
            {
                string[] tokensFromLine = searchName.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int arrayIndex = 0;
                int year = 1900;
                foreach (string token in tokensFromLine)
                {
                    int arrval;

                    if (int.TryParse(token, out arrval))
                    {
                        nums[arrayIndex] = arrval;
                        year += 10;
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", year, arrval);
                        arrayIndex++;  
                    }  
                }
                    searchName = sample2.ReadLine();
            }
        }
            return nums;
    }
}
```

Comment: put `searchName = sample2.ReadLine();` outside foreach block, because you shouldn't jump to the next line in a file if you are not finished with current (tokensFromLine);
`nums[i] = arrval;` you must increment index with each iteration of your foreach loop instead of running through the nums. so declare i outside the foreach loop and increment it like i++ before analyzing next token.

Comment: I am now getting an: Index was outside the bounds of the array exception.

Comment: looks fine. `for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)` delete this. you dont need to iterate over nums for every token. you are accessing num's position though arrayIndex.

Comment: You are correct. I had made an edit in the meantime I also forgot about that was tripping the index bounds. Thank you for the help!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I've made a few edits to print out the array and it only finds the first string of tokens and always prints that array out. Any thoughts? The txt file has more names and similar data fields.

Answer (score 0):

That sure is a lot of code, this snippet does not account for duplicates but if you were willing to work with linq, something like this might help? You could also just iterate over the file_text array using a for-loop and perhaps set your return array in that. Anyway a lot less code to mess with

```
    public int[] Search(string targetName, string fileName)
    {
        List<string> file_text = File.ReadAllLines("Files/Exercise_Files/SSA_Names_Long.txt").ToList();
        List<string> matching_lines = file_text.Where(w => w == targetName).ToList();
        List<int> nums = new List<int>();
        foreach (string test_line in matching_lines)
        {
            nums.Add(file_text.IndexOf(test_line));
        }
        return nums.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: actually you loaded entire file into the memory. i would recommend you using stream reader as it was made by the author.